# How I can mark the variables from a database (SPSS) with missing values, using Python?

Tags: python, spss

Maybe someone can help me with some tips :) We are trying to mark the variables which are filtered, so that we can build specific syntaxes with them. If I ran the part as below, I have an error :

```
    BEGIN PROGRAM.
    import spss
    newvarlist=[]
    dataCursor=[]
    oneVar=[]
    miss=[]
    counter=[]
    vars=spss.GetVariableCount()

    for i in range(vars):
        dataCursor[i]=spss.Cursor()
        oneVar[i]=dataCursor.fetchall()
        miss[i]=str(oneVar)
        counter[i]=miss.count('None')
        if counter[i]>0 :
            newvarlist.append(oneVar[i])
        dataCursor.close()
    print oneVar
    print counter
    print newvarlist
    #dataCursor.CommitCase()

    END PROGRAM.
```

below is the error that I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):    File "", line 10, in
>     IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Can you please help me or give any advice? How can I create a list with variables which are filtered from an SPSS database?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You may want to edit the question to help understand what is it you are asking. The title doesn't seem to be connected to the first paragraph in the question. Note there are multiple problems with the code, besides the IndexError, I'm having trouble guessing what it is trying to do. For one, assigning a cursor to `dataCursor[i]` but then using the entire array (`dataCursor`) as if it were a cursor object isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your lists are empty. There is no element at any `i`th position where you are trying to assign values. Use `dataCursor.append(spss.Cursor())` instead

Similar for other empty lists.

Alternatively, you can fill each list with None using star (*) operator while initializing.